i encountered error while installing next.js
I'm installing next.js for the first time on my terminal with command create-next-app@14.2.3, before that I already installed node.js with v20.13.1 version.
I get this error on my terminal:
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm error
npm error While resolving: first-next.js@0.1.0
npm error Found: eslint@undefined
npm error node_modules/eslint
npm error   dev eslint@"^8" from the root project
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer eslint@"^7.23.0 || ^8.0.0" from eslint-config-next@14.2.3
npm error node_modules/eslint-config-next
npm error   dev eslint-config-next@"14.2.3" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolve

How can I install next.js on my Mac without getting errors?

Try this, it might work for you
npx create-next-app@14.2.3 <app_name> --legacy-peer-deps

